# The complexity of determining if a fixed graph is a minor of another

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms

The result by [Robertson and Seymour](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895685710064) demonstrates an $O(n^3)$ algorithm for testing whether a fixed graph $G$ is a minor of $H$. I have two and a half questions on this topic:

1) It appears that there have been improvements to this algorithm since. What is the best-known algorithm at present?

2a) What do people conjecture to be the optimal bound?

[Mohar's algorithm for embedding on a fixed surface](http://epubs.siam.org/sidma/resource/1/sjdmec/v12/i1/p6_s1) and [Kawarabayashi's algorithm for recognizing $k$-apex graphs](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5438591) decide membership of graphs characterizable by forbidden minors in linear time, motivating the last question:

2b) Is there any reason to suspect that we can do this in linear time?

Of course, if someone already came up with a linear-time algorithm, the last two questions are silly. :)

Comment: I'm very curious to hear more about this.

Comment: I have heard that Bruce Reed and Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi have an $O(n \log n)$ time algorithm, but it hasn't been written up. This claim appears [here](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2008/01/more-on-graph-minors.html), for example.

Comment: So neither of them decided to write it up after more than three years?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a preprint by Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi, Yusuke Kobayashi, and Bruce Reed that claims a quadratic time algorithm: "[The disjoint paths problem in quadratic time](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~k_keniti/quaddp1.pdf)". It is formatted as a conference submission rather than a journal paper so I'm not sure it's possible to verify the details, though (I haven't really tried, myself).

A very recent survey by Kawarabayashi cites this as the best known result for the closely related disjoint paths problem: Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi (2011), "The Disjoint Paths Problem: Algorithm and Structure", WALCOM: Algorithms and Computation, LNCS 6552, pp. 2–7, [doi:10.1007/978-3-642-19094-0_2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-19094-0_2).

I don't know whether this means that the $O(n\log n)$ claim in Kothari's comment is vapor or whether it means that it's still at an earlier stage of being written up.

Comment: Thanks! But if the $O(n\log n)$ claim was true, wouldn't he have said something like "in preparation," seeing that this is in fact his own result?

Comment: The quadratic time paper was published in 2012: JCTB 102 (2): 424–435, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2011.07.004

Answer (score 7):

A recent paper by Isolde Adler1, Frederic Dorn, Fedor V. Fomin, Ignasi Sau and Dimitrios M. Thilikos called [Fast Minor Testing in Planar Graphs](http://www.lirmm.fr/~sau/Pubs/ADF+10b.pdf) shows that when looking for a minor $H$ on $h$ vertices in a *planar graph* $G$, this can be done in $2^{O(h)} n + O(n^2 \log n)$ time. While the dependence on $n$ is not as good as the one mentioned in the answer by David, the dependency on $h$ of this work is far superior.

Answer (score 6):

There are old results showing that linear minor testing is possible for some specific
graphs H, basically by looking at back-edge patterns in depth-first search, with
significant effort for each H, and only a few are known.  But, it is kind of like
having linear FPT for k up to 4, which can make one suspicious.

Recently discussed this issue with Rod.  My own feeling is that even topological
minor testing parameterized by H is / will be ultimately linear FPT by a "functor
project" sort of approach.  Little is yet written about this (a tiny bit in the
Bodlaender festschrift) but a very active project.  michael.fellows@uib.no